# CSV Upload errors, even after adding all attribute values

Tags: magento2, csv, magento2.3.4

I'm trying to add custom attributes using a CSV. I'm using the header additional_attributes.

I have attributes called "main category" and "sub_category", and they're in the additional_attributes column as

```
main_category="category name",sub_category="subcategory name"
```

I used the api to upload all of the product options, but I'm still getting the error:

```
Value for 'main_category' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s)
```

and it lists all of the rows.

I've reindexed, cleaned the magento cache, and flushed redis cache, but the error stays the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was putting double quotes around the values. They aren't supposed to have double quotes. I removed them, and it works.

```
main_category=categoryname
```